# multiplier algebra and intersection

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $M(A)$ be the multiplier algebra of non-unital C* algebra $A$. So $A$ is essential ideal of $M(A)$. Does there exists a dense $\ast$-subalgebra $B$ of $M(A)$, such that  $B\not\subset A$, and $B\cap A=\{0\}$?

Comment: could you make this more clear? do you mean $*$-subalgebra of just a subalgebra? Also, could you re-phrase the "it does not belong to $A$" part?

Comment: If $A$ is unital then $A=M(A)$

Comment: Also, since $A$ is non-unital the inclusion $A\subset M(A)$ is proper and $A$ is closed, so there is no need to ask for $B\not\subset A$ (since $B$ is required to be dense in $M(A)$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not always. For example, in I. Farah's [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030270919) there are references for $C^*$-algebras that have the property that $M(A)\cong\tilde{A}$, the unitization. As MaoWao proves in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4033340/dense-subalgebras-of-the-unitization-and-their-intersection-with-the-original-c/4033431#4033431), if $B\subset\tilde{A}$ is a dense subspace in $\tilde{A}$, then we cannot have $B\cap A=\{0\}$.

Comment: For clarification, is $\tilde{A}$ the algebra obtained from $A$ with adjoining the unit?(that is ,in abelian case, one-point compacification)

Comment: @Ken.Wong Yes, exactly, the unitization; the unitization is in a way "the smallest" unital $C^*$-algebra in which $A$ embeds as an essential ideal. Since $M(A)$ is the largest one, the $C^*$-algebras that have isomorphic multiplier algebra and unitization have in a sense a "unique" embedding in a unital $C^*$-algebra, as essential (closed) ideals.

Comment: Not nitpicking, but what about the case that $M(A)$ is not ismorphic to $\tilde{A}$?

Comment: @Ken.Wong Well, I have no idea! The only generalization that I can think of is that if $M(A)/A$ is finite dimensional, then the same technique works: if $\pi:M(A)\to M(A)/A$ is the quotient map and $B\cap A=0$ then $\pi$ is injective in $B$ so $\dim(B)\leq\dim(M(A)/A)$. So $B$ is finite dimensional, but then $B$ cannot be dense in $M(A)$; its closure will be finite dimensional and $M(A)$ cannot be finite dimensional, because otherwise $A$ is also finite dimensional, so $A$ is unital and we assume that $A$ is non-unital. I can't think of anything better though!