# Dense subalgebras of the unitization and their intersection with the original $C^*$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

As I was trying to figure out [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4032957/multiplier-algebra-and-intersection), I wondered if the following is true:

If $A$ is a non-unital $C^*$-algebra and $\tilde{A}$ denotes its unitization, then is it true that any $*$-subalgebra $B\subset\tilde{A}$ that is dense in $\tilde{A}$ satisfies $B\cap A\neq\{0\}$?

It seems to me that this is too much to ask and I cannot see any particular reason for this to be true. Of course, if $1_{\tilde{A}}\in B$, then the result is obvious. Also, (maybe this helps), by approximating the unit through $B$ we get a sequence of invertible elements that belong to $B$, but we cannot deduce anything about their inverses (whether they belong to $B$ or not). Note that this argument proves the result if we also assume that $B$ is a (one-sided, in general) ideal in $\tilde{A}$.

On the other hand, I cannot think of any counter-example.

I am particularly interested for the abelian case, because non-unital abelian $C^*$-algebras are continuous functions over LCH spaces, so  we can identify the unitization with the continuous functions over the one point compactification and maybe some topological arguments can prove/ disprove the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, $A$ is an ideal in $\tilde A$. Consider the quotient map $\pi\colon \tilde A\to \tilde A/A\cong \mathbb{C}$. By definition, $x\in A$ if and only if $\pi(x)=0$. If $A\cap B$ were trivial, then $\pi$ would be injective on $B$, which clearly cannot be the case unless $\dim B\leq 1$.  And it's not hard to see that $\dim B\leq 1$ can only occur under these circumstances if $A=\{0\}$, $\tilde A=\mathbb{C}$ and $B=\tilde A$. Otherwise $A\cap B\neq\{0\}$.

Comment: Impressive. Thank you very much for this smart solution!

Comment: Also one should note that it is enough to assume that $B$ is a linear space.

Comment: I have posted an answer to the linked question based on the elegant answer you gave here:)

Comment: In the end it's simply the good old formula $\dim \mathrm{ran}T+\dim\ker T=\dim V$ applied to the linear map $\pi$ on $B$, which shows that the intersection is not only non-trivial, but actually quite big.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I completely got out of track trying to get something out of the algebra structure of $B$, but things were much simpler indeed!

Comment: Actually, I missed out one edge case, but now it should be fine. @JustDroppedIn

Comment: Well, in my opinion..... $\{0\}$ is a unital $C^*$-algebra! (and we are talking about non unital ones). Just kidding with these technicalities of course, I get your point:)